# How to use select value in next or another select value MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to use tahun in first select distinct value in `AND tahun like ?` like foreach in programming language

my code is like this

```
select distinct SUBSTRING_INDEX(tahun,'/', -1) as tahun,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN choice = "A" AND tahun like '%2008%' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS A, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN choice = "B" AND tahun like '%2008%' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS B, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN choice = "C" AND tahun like '%2008%' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS C
FROM tes;
```

Sorry if my english is bad,
Thank you in advance for your answer

[distint tahun values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sg2KY.png)

Comment: `COUNT(CASE WHEN choice = "A" AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(tahun,'/', -1) = "01/02/2008" THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS A,`

Comment: tahun has more that 1 value so i use distinct in first sql

Comment: tahun has more that 1 value so i use distinct in first sql  - wrongly. please add sample data and desired outcome as text.

Comment: You cannot use output columnA alias in another output columnB expression. You must use the expression of the columnA instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `GROUP` the records instead of put `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(tahun,'/', -1) as tahun,
    SUM(CASE WHEN choice = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS A, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN choice = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS B, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN choice = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS C
FROM tes
GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(tahun,'/', -1)
ORDER BY 1;
```